# Build of Poco fails on Mac Catalina when linking libPocoCrypto.dylib

Tags: macos, poco, libcrypto

I cloned the latest version of the Poco libraries source code on to my Mac and attempted to build it per the instructions using CMake. Everything proceeded fine until it reached a point where it was trying to link the libPocoCrypt.dylib library. Even though the C++ compilation worked with out error, the link resulted in the following output

```
ld: cannot link directly with dylib/framework, your binary is not an allowed client of /usr/lib/libcrypto.dylib for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [lib/libPocoCrypto.80.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Crypto/CMakeFiles/Crypto.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Doing some research, I discovered that Apple doesn't want applications linking against its libcrypto library and thus, the resulting error messages. The question then is, what do I need to do here to make this work?